# pthread in main and plugin?

Tags: c++, c, plugins, pthreads

I am running on Ubuntu 14.04 and compile and link with gcc/g++. The main consists of about 30 files and 20 plugins are called by main. I use `-pthread` as compiler option and I do `#include <pthread.h>`. My questions are:

1. Is it enough to put #include  in main only or do I have to put it in all files which belong to main? I guess that the answer is also true for plugins.
2. Do I have to put #include  in all plugin mains and compile with -pthread even if they don’t use threads or is the call of a plugin already a thread?

Comment: Either you compile as C (gcc) or C++ (g++). YOu certainly do not compile the same code with both. C and C++ are different languages. Pick one!

Comment: And neither language sopports plugins. What do you mean? See [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: No, it is mostly c code and few c++!

Comment: Plugins are programs which are called at run time and are of course supported :). You can add and remove plugins and they are initialised at start.

Comment: You provided information redundant to me and missed the point. Not sure how that plugin information is realted to compiling `main` - even more as plugins are called at run-time. So your comment did not clarify anything.

Comment: Sorry your statement was that c/c++ doesn't support plugins and this is not the case. What is your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101106/discussion-between-musbach-and-olaf).

Comment: Please provide a link to that C/C++ language you mention. I actually was talking about C and C++, which are different languages. If you provide that link, please point me at the specification for its plugin-system.

Comment: More information in the chat ...

Comment: To summarise: you did not answer any request. I asked about the languages. The links provided are not part of any of the ISO **language** standards. Not to mention the still not provided C/C++ specification. I did not write you cannot **implement** a plugin interface! That is logical for a general purpose language. You did not even mention **which** plugin interface you use. Still feel free to prove me wrong by providing links to the sections in the ISO standards of C and C++, or the C/C++ language.

Comment: Has somebody an answer, if one has to put #include only in main or in all files (see first question)?  PS: Please only people who know something about pthreads. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll go out on a limb here and assume that when you say "plugins" you actually mean "external functions", i.e. functions used but not defined in a given C source file.

When you call any external function from your code, there needs to at least be a declaration of that function so that the compiler knows the proper way to call it.  Header files typically contain those needed declarations.

For example, if you want to use the `strcpy` function, you need to `#include <string.h>`, since that file contains a declaration for `strcpy`.  If `strcpy` is not called anyplace in a given C file (nor is any other function declared in `string.h`), then you do not need to `#include <string.h>` in that file.

Similarly for `pthread.h`, you only need to include it if you call `pthread_create` or any of the other functions declared in that file from within that C source file.

When it comes to linking, if any of the source files that are linked together to create your executable use any of the pthread functions, then you need to pass `-pthread` when creating the executable.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit vague, the "main" of 30 files looks like the "exe" i.e the executable program and plugins are shared lib  or dll. Also seems like you want to make your project multi threaded. If its already a multi threaded program then attach to it using gdb(in case u r on linux) and use "info threads" which will list the threads or "cat /proc/[pid]/status | grep Threads" , it will show number of threads.. where pid is the process id of you running program.

If -pthread is used as an compiler option but if it is not linking with pthread lib i.e somewhere in you build/make program there should be -lpthread; then your program is not multi threaded even though u r including the header file, as no thread API is used.